# How is a sql junction table displayed in an entity relationship diagramm

Tags: erd, entity-relationship

Entity Relationship Assumptions:

1. N Testplan has M Teststep.
2. 1 Testplan has N Screenshots

Therefore I have a `TestplanTeststep` table and a `Screenshot` table related to the `TestplanTeststep` table.

**Question**: but how can I express this with an ERD ?

When I look back at point 2.) then it is not true that a `Testplan` has N `Screenshots`, because a `Testplan` can not have `Screenshots`. Actually the `TestplanTeststep` has the N `Screenshots`, but afair ERD`s are conceptual models not physical (sql tables).

**Question again**: How can I express with ERD that a `Screenshot` belongs to a `TestplanTeststep` but not `Testplan`?

Answer (score 6):

All your relationships are exactly-one to many (i.e. 1 testplan has 0-n teststeps and 1 teststep has 0-n screenshots). Your diagram should then be as follows:

[image]